# Give the labels to midpoints of a triangle

Tags: tkz-euclide

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(6,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(3,5){A}

\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,A)

\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{D}

\tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{E}

\tkzDefMidPoint(C,A) \tkzGetPoint{F}

\tkzDefPoint[label={[align=left]above:$A(a,b)$},xshift=00mm](3,5){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label={[align=right]left:$B(c,d)$},xshift=00mm](0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label={[align=left]right:$C(e,f)$},xshift=00mm](6,0){C}

\tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
\tkzLabelPoints[right,below](E)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](F)

\tkzDrawSegment(D,E)
\tkzDrawSegment(E,F)
\tkzDrawSegment(D,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Question: How can i give the labels (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and (x3,y3) to points D, E and F respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `\tkzLabelPoint` instead of `\tkzLabelPoints`, you can specify the label as well:

```
\tkzLabelPoint[left](D){$(x_1,y_1)$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](E){$(x_2,y_2)$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](F){$(x_3,y_3)$}
```