# inserting $pi$ in $x$-axis using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-fct

I would like to insert the labels in math mode just like in a regular math expression.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-1.1,xmax=13.2,ymin=-2,ymax=2]
\tkzDrawX[trig=1]
\tkzDrawY[noticks]
\tkzFct[domain=-1:13]{cos(x)}
\tkzDefPoint(0,-1){-1}
\tkzDefPoint(0,1){1}
\tkzDefPoint(pi/2,0){pi/2}
\tkzDefPoint(pi,0){pi}
\tkzDefPoint(3*pi/2,0){3pi/2}
\tkzDefPoint(2*pi,0){2pi}
\tkzDefPoint(5*pi/2,0){5pi/2}
\tkzDefPoint(3*pi,0){3pi}
\tkzDefPoint(7*pi/2,0){7pi/2}
\tkzDefPoint(4*pi,0){4pi}
\tkzDrawPoint(pi/2)
\tkzDrawPoint(-1)
\tkzDrawPoint(1)
\tkzDrawPoint(3pi/2)
\tkzDrawPoint(pi)
\tkzDrawPoint(2pi)
\tkzDrawPoint(5pi/2)
\tkzDrawPoint(3pi)
\tkzDrawPoint(7pi/2)
\tkzDrawPoint(4pi)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](-1)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](1)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](pi/2)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](pi)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](3pi/2)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](2pi)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](5pi/2)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](3pi)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](7pi/2)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](4pi)
\tkzHLine[dashed]{1}
\tkzHLine[dashed]{-1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

hete it is what I got

[image]

Comment: Please add your code without the `>`s.

Comment: Use \tkzLabelPoint instead of \tkzLabelPoints, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333460/121799).